# Getting error "Unknown web method" when trying to call aspx.vb page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I know this has been asked, but I keep getting this error on a method I added, no matter what I do.

I think I've read all the posts on this (and have Googled it all day long), but nothing seems to work.  I'm new to web development.

Is there something I need to do so that the page gets refreshed somehow?  It works fine on my machine, but when I do a clean/rebuild solution and a new build, and then try to access it via the server, I get the error.

I've tried removing the "Shared"...  The sPath is correct...

```
function SaveServerSideAJAXContinue(SaveMode) 
{

var sPath = window.location.pathname;
var data = JSON.stringify("");
var JSONData = "{ Data:" + data + "}";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: JSONData,
    url: sPath + "/GetPreSaveMethod",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (jsonresult) {
        eval(jsonresult.d);
        PerformServerSave(SaveMode);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, testStatus, errorThrown) {
        var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=1000, height=800");
        myWindow.document.write(jqXHR.responseText);

        PerformServerSave(SaveMode);
    }
});
}


   <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function GetPreSaveMethod(ByVal Data As String) As String
        Return GetPreSave()
    End Function


    Private Shared Function GetPreSave() As String

        Dim MidasObj As MidasObjInstance = MidasObjGet()
        Dim PreSaveMethod As String = MidasObj.UserForm.PreSaveMethod

        Return PreSaveMethod
    End Function
```

If any of this looks goofy, it's probably because I've been trying all kinds of stuff and my mind is shot at this point.  Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should post some sort of code to show what you currently have tried.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry...somehow I hit enter before I was done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try resolving the webmethod and putting that in a JS variable then posting to that.

```
<script> var webMethodUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/<ASMXILENAMEHERE>/GetPreSaveMethod") %>';</script>
```

Comment: That was a great suggestion...even though I was "positive" that the URL was right, it wasn't.  Trying this method made me realize this and rethink where my web method should go.  Thanks so much...I really appreciate it!  This might help some other lost soul who thinks they know where they're going.  :)